# Timed Ajax Process Continues after User Leaves Page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have javascript that is refreshing a portion of a rails generated view through a JS request every 2.5 seconds in order to update a simple progress bar.

```
function refreshPage(){
  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      dataType:"script"
  })
}

setInterval(function(){
    refreshPage();
}, 2500);
```

For some reason this continues even after the user leaves the page. This happens in both Development and Production. The only way to stop it is for the user to go to a different page and F5 to refresh.

This is probably something simple I'm missing. Do I need some kind of "progress bar is done, stop sending JS requests" method?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. All scripts should stop when you load a new page.

Comment: Sounds right, but it IS happening. Rails doing something strange maybe?

Comment: Rails can't change how the browser works.

Comment: I didn't think so. Let me know if you have any information to provide. Otherwise jvillian's solution is fine for my use case.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. I created a simple web page that just has your Javascript code, and started watching my webserver access log. When I opened the page, I started seeing accesses to the AJAX URL. When I went to another page or closed the browser window, the hits on the webserver stopped.

Comment: Thanks for those details. I must be doing something wrong somewhere. I'm taking a look to see if I can identify anything.

Comment: How are you determining that the script is still running?

Comment: The JS request is submitting a query to check if values in a small MySQL table have changed. I'm watching the ActiveRecord event repeat every 2.5 seconds in the rails server output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use clearInterval(intervalID) as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) as you need to explicitly stop the timer that you started with setInterval().

Comment: This worked for me. The refreshPage call checks for the presence and value of the progress bar id. If the progress bar reaches 0 or the user navigates away from the page, the refreshing stops via a clearInterval call.

Comment: @Barmar - It's a fair question. But, the answer depends on the developer's design. I tend to use OO design in my javascript, so I tend to have a class that is responsible for starting and stopping timers depending on what's happening in the app (on the client, mostly). But, I know other people use a more functional approach to their js design, in which case I imagine the answer would be different. So, I'm sorry to say, I think the answer is in truth, *in depends*.

Comment: @Chakron - Glad it works for you! Good luck on your project.

Comment: What I meant is what should trigger clearing the interval? How would it know that the user has navigated away, since scripts stop when you navigate away?

Comment: @Barmar - Full disclosure, I'm no javascript expert. I'm not sure, however, that it's *absolutely* true that a script stops running when a user leaves a page. According to http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval, setInterval() has window as 'this'. So, it may be true that the timer is still attached (and running) when the user goes to a new page. I think, however, with a F5, the window variable gets reset - which is why the timer goes away on an F5. But, again, this is a bit beyond my expertise.